# How can I use the block editor for a 404 page in WordPress without redirecting from /404

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a WordPress website and a custom theme, and of course a `404.php` file. I have followed [this amazing guide](https://highrise.digital/blog/how-to-make-your-wordpress-404-template-editable-using-the-block-editor/) on making the 404 page template editable with the block editor.

My components on the 404 page appear correctly when I go to `/404` (or for that matter, any invalid link), however, when going to `/404`, the user is **redirected to `/404-2`** This is the behavior I would like to fix. When the user goes to `/abc` (an invalid page) then the 404 is shown and they ae not redirected and still on `/abc` (which is as intended).

I checked the page in WP and the URL slug is set to `/404-2` and attempting to change it to 404 just defaults back to 404. It seems that this is due to [404 being a number and default WP behavior](https://themes.artbees.net/forums/topic/404-page-slug/). But this just tells me why the problem occurs; I do not know how to override or correct this behavior. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by hooking onto `do_redirect_guess_404_permalink`

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_redirect_guess_404_permalink/

```php
<?php

function stop_redirect_guess() {
    return false;
}

add_filter( 'do_redirect_guess_404_permalink', 'stop_redirect_guess');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've found, the page title "404" (or any numeric title) will always be rewritten to "404-2", this ensures the title is distinct/never confused with a numeric post/page id.

A simple solution would be to rename the page to "404 page" and update the php function to `get_page_by_title( '404 page' )`. This would give your page more SEO friendly url of `/404-page` and not require trying to change permalinks/rewriting of the *.htaccess* file.

An alternative to consider is migrating your custom theme to a [block theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/block-themes/block-theme-setup/) if using WordPress 5.9 or higher. This would enable you to create a true "404" page template using the Block Editor that can be edited via the `Site Editor > Templates`. The [Site Editor enables you to add new templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/block-themes/creating-new-themes-using-the-site-editor/), save and export them for easily creating your own templates for your custom theme. Starting with a base theme like [Twenty Twenty Two](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwentytwo/) is a good way to see what is possible. It's very different to creating a "classic" php-based theme; though the advantage of block templates and the Site Editor is a great benefit for future-proofing your theme.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The problem wasn't the page title; I could rename it to "404 page" or "abc123" and it would still have a slug other than "404" and redirect. I found the answer was to hook on to `do_redirect_guess_404_permalink` as I've posted below.

Comment: @Justin No worries, happy that you were able to find the solution! I forgot about that old hook as I've been working on new templates for all pages.